# What does the redirection operator "<" do in shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I  came across the below shell command:

```
$prog.sh < file_name.json
```

I know it reads from a file, but how and where does `prog.sh` load the file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by load? Just a simple `cat` in the script will print the file.

Comment: Shell script is not a language with universal semantics, it depends on the actual shell. So, in your case it's either the interpretation of BASH or ZSH I guess. For further info, I'd suggest the according manuals, if those don't help, ask specific follow-up questions.

Comment: @anubhava Load mean how to read and process content from json file

Comment: Just put `jq '.'` in your script and `jq` will load and read your file

Answer (score 2):

Every program has three open file handles at startup, one of which is standard input. Normally, the file handles are inherited from the parent process. The `<` operator tells the shell that, instead of passing its standard input to `prog.sh`, to open `file_name.json` instead and give *that* file handle to `prog.sh` as its standard input.

Comment: Minor quibble; when there is no redirection operator, the shell doesn't 'pass' its stdin to `prog.sh`.  The file descriptors are inherited and the shell is unaware of that.  It's more passive than active.  Perhaps say "instead of allowing prog.sh to inherit its standard input"

Comment: Good point; it's a side effect of the call to `fork` that causes the child to have a copy of its parent's file handles. With an input redirection, the shell then uses `dup`(?) to replace the inherited handle with the redirected file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$prog.sh < file_name.json
```

As you rightly guess. The `<` is meant for redirecting the input from a file so that your script will read from the file which will be the (temporary) `stdin`(fd0).

> it read from a file, but how and where prog.sh will load the file

It depends on how you plan to go about it. Any command in the script that expects an input from the `stdin` will now read from the file. The `new line` character in the text file (usually) stands for  the <kbd>↵</kbd> in the `stdin`.

Comment: It is not correct to say that the 'script will not wait for input from the stdin'.  The script does read its input from its stdin, and its stdin is the file.  'Any command ... that expects an input from stdin' still reads from stdin.  I make these points because it seems you are conflating "stdin" with "terminal", and they are radically different things.